# How to get element by point in jQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get an element by specifying the point values in page.

```
var point = this.svgRenderer.getPoint(serPoint, chart);
```

This will return exact point location of the page. That point contains some SVG element either circle or rectangle or image or other elements. I want to get the element based on the point location. Is this possible?

Answer (score 9):

```
document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.elementFromPoint

Comment: i have used this but it throws null element. document.elementFromPoint(590,-324). in that location circle element is there. but it returns null

Comment: <circle id="container_svg_circlesymbol4" cx="589.1666666666667" cy="-321" r="7.0710678118654755" fill="url(#container_svg_symbol1Gradient)" stroke-width="1" stroke="Gray"/>. circle element with cx="589" and cy="-321" so passed 589,-321. but it returns null.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wwQEL/5/ (the x and y are relative to the document, the above would only work if the your svg is 0,0 in the document, see the fiddle)

Comment: if am using like that <g translate=transform(73,517)> <circle ...></g> .in that case how can i get the circle element by specifying the point values

Comment: Assuming you meant `transform=translate` it works just fine http://jsfiddle.net/wwQEL/6/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29093/discussion-between-siva-rajini-and-david-mulder)

Answer (score 3):

why don't you just use `document.elementFromPoint`.

the  example in the link below shows how it works .

[get element by point](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.elementFromPoint?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%3adocument.elementFromPoint)

Comment: if am using like that <g translate=transform(73,517)> <circle ...></g> .in that case how can i get the circle element by specifying the point values

Comment: take a look at the fiddle posted above by david mudler .

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try getIntersectionList from [SVG-DOM](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#__svg__SVGSVGElement__getIntersectionList) using a rectangle with a height and width of one as parameter:

Full example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100" onclick="elementsAtEventPosition(event)">
    <script>
        function elementsAtEventPosition(event) {
            var svgRootNode = document.documentElement;
            var rect = svgRootNode.createSVGRect();
            rect.x = event.clientX;
            rect.y = event.clientY;
            rect.width = 1;
            rect.height = 1;
            alert(svgRootNode.getIntersectionList(rect, svgRootNode).length);
        }
    </script>
    <rect x="10" y="10" width="50" height="50" fill="black" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" />
</svg>
```

Comment: if am using like that <g translate=transform(73,517)> <circle ...></g> .in that case how can i get the circle element by specifying the point values

Comment: Added an example to the answer to clarify the API usage